# Using WebImage in asp.net core razor mvc

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following this [sample](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/9-working-with-images) for working with WebImage. However I'm using asp-net core mvc in vs code.

Since there is no System.Web.Helpers where should I reference WebImage from? I tried searching and there are no explanation in aspnet mvc github wiki.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to replace `WebImage` with a more suitable alternative for asp.net core, then `IFormFile` is your friend.

You can bind directly to an `IFormFile` if the parameter name matches the name of your form input field. Or, you can use the below. *(Note the change from Request.Files to Request.Form.Files when moving from .net framework to core)*

```
IFormFile inputFile = Request.Form.Files["uploadInputFieldName"];
```

Instead of the `ContentLength` property, you may find you need to reference `Length` instead.

When it comes to saving the file to the local file system (if that is what you are after), then swap out the `SaveAs` method call for this:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filePathWithSecureName, FileMode.Create))
{
    await inputFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

More information on file uploads in core, including security considerations, this page is worth a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

to upload webimage

```
<input type="file" name="updoc" id="upoc" class="form-control" />
```

**and retrieve in controller by** 
 in Controller

```
   HttpPostedFileBase casteCertificate = Request.Files["updoc"];
```

Add multipart on your html begin form to retrive stream data from view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("controller", "action", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "myForm", id = "myForm" }))
```

Passing image to View

```
 ViewBag.pic = urlofwebimage;
```

**in view**

```
 <img id="Userpic" class="pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 7px" width="180" height="100" src="@ViewBag.pic" />
```

else u can also do model binding of Image Url

Comment: But can I use WebImage in aspnet core?

Comment: Initially, no.  It's part of System.Web.   But, you can manual add System.Web to your asp.net core solution, but I recommend staying with core and not asp.net 4.6 dlls.

Answer (score 0):

To use WebImage in a Razor page make sure you call the using library on top of your page like this.

> @using System.Web.Helpers;

Be sure to first get System.Web.Helpers from Nuget.